# Display errors in MySQL Workbench

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-20.04

MySQL Workbench is displaying a series of boxes instead of characters in the results screen, and a number of elements are disappearing from the window when a query is run.

I'm receiving a number of GTK `out of memory` errors in the syslog when this happens too:

```
drawing failure for widget 'gtkmm__GtkPaned': out of memory
```

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and installed MySQL Workbench via `snap`.

How do I fix this?

**Before executing query:**

[image: Screenshot before running query]

**After executing query:**

[image: Screenshot of glitch]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I dug further into the logs and found the root cause of the issue. If I ran `mysql-workbench-community` from the command line, the first error messages I received were:

```
Pango-WARNING **: 11:17:24.882: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'TeXGyreHeros 11'
Pango-WARNING **: 11:17:24.882: font_face status is: file not found
Pango-WARNING **: 11:17:24.882: scaled_font status is: file not found
```

This was the same for a few different fonts.

It's worth noting that I had recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. It turns out there was an issue with my font cache, similar to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1228809/1057691) for Chromium, the solution was to re-generate the cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig 
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

```
find ~/snap/mysql-workbench-community/ -name 'fontconfig'
```

Then clear out the relevant snap font cache (look for `.cache`):

```
rm -rf ~/snap/mysql-workbench-community/common/.cache/fontconfig/
```

Then restart MySQL Workbench, and everything should run smoothly.
I'm not sure why this fixed the GTK out of memory errors, but they no longer occur.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it happened on the first time running mysql-workbench after install.

I stop and then restart mysql-workbench, everything is OK.

Comment: This is strange but it works. Closing and reopening the workbench makes the texts visible.

Comment: Worked for me also. How it happened might be important: it was after install and first run. Password permissions weren't enabled, so I enabled them and didn't restart the app. Not sure if this was the culprit, but seems likely.